# 3D Window Managers?

Tags: window-manager, 3d-graphics

Does anyone know of a window manager that displays your files as a 3d city like in the movie Jurassic Park or Hackers?  I know about bumptop but it makes your desktop look like a desktop (boring).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll do better than that! [File System Navigator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fsn) is literally the file manager used in Jurassic Park! It WAS a Unix system! She DID know that!

Comment: +1 for SGI!  note it's actually **fsn (File System Navigator)** (not Manager)

Comment: I actually have a copy of that, not that it would help anyone without an SGI workstation. But there you are http://factormystic.net/sa/fsn/

Answer (score 6):

The Linux port of fsn is called [FSV](http://fsv.sourceforge.net/).  The site [Nooface](http://nooface.net/3dui.shtml) lists a bunch of 3D window managers, including fsv, with a variety of effects.  Some link are to not just window managers.  For example, what better way to kill a process?

[image: doom]

Comment: That is incredible.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like a city, but [**SphereXP**](https://web.archive.org/web/20090430122318/http://www.spheresite.com/spherexp.html) is a 3D desktop manager, where windows are put inside a sphere.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 2):

[One of my favorite YouTube videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xC5uEe5OzNQ) compares the hardware-accelerated 3D window managers of Windows Vista ("Aero") and Linux Ubuntu ("Beryl").