# How to immediately kill orphaned TCP connection?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, tcp

Closing orphaned TCP connections is surprisingly difficult in Linux. This issue has been raised [here](https://superuser.com/questions/127863/manually-closing-a-port-from-commandline), [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71940/killing-tcp-connection-in-linux), [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/7689/how-do-i-get-rid-of-sockets-in-fin-wait1-state), and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/67039/how-to-kill-windows-zombie-tcp-connections); however, neither of the approaches worked for me.

Calling `close()` doesn't work because there is no associated process. Installing `CurrPorts` won't work because I'm not on Windows. The approach of setting `tcp_max_orphans` to zero doesn't succeed (and I assume that even if it would, it wouldn't kill the connection immediately). Running `tcpkill` doesn't work because there is no active traffic. Running `killcx` fails with `no response from child, operation may have failed`. Google's [tcp_killer](https://github.com/google/tcp_killer) fails with `Socket not found for connection`. Setting short timeout and waiting it out is not an option because I must reuse the IP and port immediately.

Throughout all of this `netstat -tp` persistently shows that the connection is alive:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0    156 localhost:54494         localhost:xmpp-client   FIN_WAIT1   -
```

What is the way to immediately kill this TCP connection?

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I've come across (albeit a bit brute force), is this nice kernel module called [drop-tcp-sock](https://github.com/milabs/drop-tcp-sock) made by another [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/651394) of the StackExchange community. It uses `inet_twsk_deschedule_put()` of the Linux kernel and although this function is meant to force-kill TCP connections in the `TIME_WAIT` state, it worked for killing `FIN_WAIT1` as well.

This module can be loaded with:

```
git clone https://github.com/milabs/drop-tcp-sock.git
cd drop-tcp-sock && make
insmod ./drop-tcp-sock.ko
```

and then used (in my scenario) with:

```
echo "127.0.0.1:54494 127.0.0.1:5222" >/proc/net/tcpdropsock
```